# Gmail getElementById('canvas_frame') keeps returning null in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, null, gmail

i'm trying to write JavaScript code for a Gmail extension, and when I'm trying to get the canvas frame I, "getElementById" keeps returning the `null` value.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var doc2 = document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentDocument;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: It means that the element with css selector `#canvas_frame` does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Because the iframe with ID `canvas_frame` does not need to exist in Gmail.

To get a reference to the relevant document, you can first try to get a reference to `iframe#canvas_frame`, and if that fails, check if the current context is correct:

```
var doc2 = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');
if (doc2) {
    doc2 = doc2.contentDocument;
} else if (document.getElementById('js_frame')) {
    // If #canvas_frame does not exist, but #js_frame does, then Gmail renders
    // everything in the main (=top) frame
    doc2 = document;
} // else not Gmail's document, and doc2 === null
```