# How to use getElementsByClassName function in order to get the "send" button in Gmail compose page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm using JavaScript to write a Gmail extension for the Chrome browser.
I'm trying to get the `send` button element from the `Compose` page using this code:

```
SendButton  = document.getElementById('js_frame').contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('T-I J-J5-Ji Bq nS T-I-KE L3')[0];
```

But then I keep getting a message saying that the `typeof SendButton is undefined`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `contentWindow.document` instead of `contentDocument`.

Comment: Unfortunately - not working...

Comment: @Teemu `frameElement.contentWindow` is `undefined` within a content script. Furthermore, all modern browsers (and IE8+) support the `contentDocument` property.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the info, I suppose I could learn to use `contentDocument` too : ).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wrong document.

Gmail's `#js_frame` is an invisible frame which is responsible for non-UI stuff (its body only contains `<script>` tags, FYI). In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032301/gmail-getelementbyidcanvas-frame-keeps-returning-null-in-google-chrome), I already showed how to get a correct reference:

- `document.getElementById('canvas_frame').contentDocument` if existent
- `document` if `#canvas_frame` does not exists, but `js_frame` does. js_frame` is used to exclude non-Gmail pages at the Gmail domain, such as the Help pages.

So, you after getting `doc2` (see [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032326/938089)), you need to query the element on that document:

```
// Paste declaration of doc2 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14032326/938089
// And to get the button when available
if (doc2) {
    sendButton = doc2.getElementsByClassName('T-I J-J5-Ji Bq nS T-I-KE L3')[0];
}
```

Comment: Gmail changes its classes per user and I think ever per composed email. For instance, mine for the send Button is `T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3`

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga No it doesn't: The class names are hardcoded. The selector in my answer applies to the Send button in the old compose (regardless of its hover/focus state), your selector is used for the one in the new Compose.

Comment: I see, at least the `T-I J-J5-Ji` ones seems to match with the old version. How would you then code for a backwards compatible version? I don't dislike your answer, but if a developer stumbles upon your code, would he/she be able to understand what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga In the context of a Gmail extension, what makes the name `sendButton` hard to understand?

Comment: Although the variable name is appropriate, the code hardly helps to a future developer to see what are you trying to achieve. What if it gets minified and the var name gets replaced? Code should be descriptive... if a non-developer can't understand what are you trying to do chances are that you could improve it someway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the class or the id attribute of the Send button because they change everytime a compose field is created, and may even change per user. What do we know about the button then?

- It's innerHTML is "Send" (See footnote)
- It has a role attribute with the value "button"
- It's inside a "Compose New Message" container, that also has other labels as "From", "To" (See footnote 2)

With that information, we can use a nice Xpath query in native Javascript that retrieves our button.

```
var xpath = '//div[@role="button" and text()="Send"]'
var query = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var button = query.iterateNext();
```

If you are using a library as jQuery, feel free to use it with the css selectors `[role="button"]` and a filter function provided in a previous answer.

This could be improved with the tables information appending it as a parent, but this should be enough (you can read more about it in the [Developer Mozilla Introduction to Xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)). Hopefully the answer provides a good performance.

**UPDATE:** It seems Gmail does stick with some classes for some things (classes like `T-I J-J5-Ji` seem to be shared between the old and new version). Yet, I wouldn't use it, if other developer stumbles upon that class and you are getting the button through only that, there's no way he or she can understand what you are getting, specially if there are no comments and a poor variable name is used.

A solution that actually retrieves the answer uses a CSS query selector that looks like `div > div > div > div > table div`; I wouldn't use it neither for the same reason. Plus, it reminds me of a poor descriptive [Regular Expression](http://theprofoundprogrammer.com/post/28623204754/text-regular-expressions-photograph-of-a). You are not only coding for you, but also to the future yourself that may have no idea about the project.

---

<sup>Footnote: OR the equivalent to the user's language. I'm not sure if all the users have their Gmail in english, but I wouldn't make that assumption. If I were you, I would create a dictionary with the locales of the most common keywords for "Send" and iterate evaluate through most of them. The amount of languages you could iterate through could be limited to languages [Gmail support](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=17091).</sup>

<sup>Footnote 2: Actually, when you press "Compose" it adds the labels "From" and "To", but if you don't fill them right away, they dissapear, showing just some divs with the innerHTML's "Recipients" and "Subject"</sup>

Comment: The class name you're suggesting is **not** sufficiently unique. These are generic class names for styling the button. Furthermore, your selector only works in the English version of Gmail. Intentionally neglecting non-English users is a bad move.

Comment: What class name are you talking about? I'm not using a class at all, as I'm not certain whether Gmail changes that on which basis. And as I stated in the footnote: ` If I were you, I would create a dictionary with the locales of the most common keywords for "Send" and iterate evaluate through most of them. It should be no more than 10`

Comment: And why are you neglecting the next text? ... "Yet, I wouldn't use it". The first thing I write in my answer is "You can't rely on the class or the id attribute of the Send button". I came to this conclusion after looking at other solutions and comparing to my own Gmail data, where classes were different. Agreed on the language, but we are now making assumptions on whether the application is meant to be international or just for english speakers.

Comment: "It seems Gmail does stick with some classes for some things (classes like T-I J-J5-Ji ..." suggests that that class name can be used to select the right button. Your suggestion would require an update to the application every time when a new language is added/supported (besides, Gmail supports 56 languages (as of writing), so why restrict your app to 10 languages only?).

Comment: I agreed that restricting the dictionary to 10 seems silly. The number seemed right when thinking about the most spoken languages in the world, let me update that. Oh, and the comment I made about the classes was after analyzing other answers as well as our previous discussion in the comments; I added that to ensure that when the OP reads other answers and comments, he can have all the information when approaching his/her solution.